# A good gradle nunit plugin?

Tags: .net, testing, build, nunit, gradle

For whatever reason I have got in touch with Gradle as a build system and I think it totally rocks. I have been using rake to build my windows projects (visual studio solutions) for some years now and I find Gradle superior to rake in many aspects.

Now, I want to find a good nunit plugin that allows me to execute `gradle build` command and this one will detect the test task, find nunit (probably located in the packages directory if the project was created with nuget) and execute the tests.
Another way it could be that allows me to configure nunit properties (such as location of the nunit installation and the nunit file containing references and targets to the tests I want to execute.

If this plugin has not been created, I would love to contribute and create it (pushing it to github) but I will need a little bit of help as I am new to this. (and I really don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something out there)

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this might help you (https://github.com/bamboo/gradle-dotnet-plugins) (haven't used it though)

Comment: Thanks Vagaus, I looked that plugin (haven't played with it) my concerned was it specifies Unity. Will take a look again and post my findings.

Comment: rodrigoelp, how did this go?

Comment: I tried out the gradle-dotnet-pluings but couldn't get it to work with nuget packages and I think I had to install unity to get it to work, which seems a very odd requirement to get it to work. I started writing a plugin to do this but I've been unable to focus on it.

Is there anybody else interested on a plugin like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin has been created by @muryoh for nunit: [gradle-nunit-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-nunit-plugin)

It is available as both an old/new style plugin, cf [Gradle Plugin Portal page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.ullink.nunit).

This plugin is only about nunit execution, but you can use it together with [gradle-msbuild-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-msbuild-plugin) (and likely [gradle-nuget-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-nuget-plugin), and eventually [gradle-opencover-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-opencover-plugin)) if you need the build (resp. nuget restore / coverage).

You can see them in use in [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) project.